# Rename Tab and Labels by Profile

Tags: profile

Do you know if there is a way to use ‘Rename Tab and Labels’ by Profile?  The use case would be Profile “XXX” would use the default Tab and Label Names, while Profile “YYY” uses the override names and labels.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

We cannot rename the tab for each user profile. As per my understanding rename will be applied to all profiles.

But we can get this working using jquery

```
var renameTab = "{!($Profile.Name)}";
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function () {
    if (renameTab == 'System Administrator') {
        j$("#tabBar").find("#Account_Tab").find("a").text("New Account");
    }
})
```